# Access remote Postgres server with pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've got pgAdmin running on my XP machine. There's a Centos machine running a Postgres server on the network. The Postgres server `pg_hba.conf` file has the following lines

```
TYPE      DATABASE    USER      CIDR-ADDRESS       METHOD
host      all         all       10.0.0.68/32       trust
local     mydb        myuser                       password
local     all         postgres                     ident
host      mydb        myuser    10.0.0.68/32       password
host      all         postgres  10.0.0.68/32       trust
```

My `postgresql.conf` file has the following line:

```
listen_address = 'localhost, 10.0.20.10'
```

`nmap -sS 10.0.20.10` shows:

```
PORT      STATE     SERVICE
5432/tcp  open      postgresql
```

I can ssh into a bash shell on the server, but I can't connect with pgAdmin. I get the following:

> could not connect to server: No route to host(0x00002751/10065) Is the
>   server running on host "10.0.20.10" and accepting TCP/IP connections
>   on port 5432?

I've no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Make sure that Postgres server was restarted (e.g. `listen_address` change requires such restart). I guess that might be rather some firewall issue.

Comment: Try to reach port 5432 with ssh, Try it on numeric ip-adres (instead of hostname) in pgadmin3 (could be a stale DNS entry) Is there any NAT/firewalling involved?

Comment: Yes it was a firewall issue. 'service iptables stop' enabled the connection. I'll just write a rule to allow the connection. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Aidan found the solution himself:

It was a firewall issue.

```
service iptables stop
```

enabled the connection. I'll just write a rule to allow the connection.

Comment: you could just have easily added an iptable rule to forward to the right port instead of bringing down your firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose server's IP address is `10.0.20.10` then you could just add these iptable rules as @Dark Star1 proposed in comments:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d 10.0.20.10 --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.20.10 --sport 5432 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```