# Connect pgAdmin to a remote server container

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, pgadmin

I have a remote Linux Ubuntu server that has a container running PostgreSQL database. Is possible to use my local pgAdmin and connect to this remote server database container?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You need to open the port, `5432` (default), for all `IP` (not recommended for security reason) or any specific `IP` address from where you want to connect. Before that add the client `IP` address in the `pg_hba.conf` file. Restart the postgresql server after the changes.
This has been already asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286264/access-remote-postgres-server-with-pgadmin

Comment: @devd I know how to access a database running on the server but what when the database is running in Docker?

Comment: This might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside
https://medium.com/@lvthillo/connect-from-local-machine-to-postgresql-docker-container-f785f00461a7